# Azure function managed identity- Value of "AzureWebJobsStorage" app setting is invalid

Tags: azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am creating an azure function with system managed identity to be used to connect to storage account. As per documentation, the i have added the required role to storage account so that function can access the storage. Also, i have replaced AzureWebJobsStorage appsetting with AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName and have provided the storage account name.
The function is working fine but I am getting a message in azure portal saying

Value of "AzureWebJobsStorage" app setting is invalid.

The strange thing is that i was not seeing this error till tomorrow and have started seeing it today only.
Followed this one completely
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/use-managed-identity-instead-of-azurewebjobsstorage-to-connect-a/ba-p/3657606

Does anyone know if I am missing anything?

Comment: Check the **AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName** app setting is correctly configured with the name of your storage account. Make sure there are no typos or mistakes in the configuration

Comment: Double-check that the managed identity associated with your Azure Function has been granted the necessary role (such as Storage Blob Data Owner,  Storage Account Contributor, and Storage Queue Data Contributor) on the storage account.

Comment: Sometimes, Azure portal messages can be misleading or delayed. If your function is working correctly and you've verified the configuration, this message may be erroneous or related to a temporary issue on the Azure side. You can try refreshing the portal or waiting for some time to see if the message disappears

Comment: thanks @DasariKamali , if there is only AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName  and i can access the keys, doesn't that mean that it is using managed identity. Is there any way of validating it. i have waited and redployed multiple times and the issue exists. Though it is not an error message with a red cross but a blue information message with info symbol

Comment: Can you confirm, if are you trying this in any coding language in the Azure portal to trigger any function?

Comment: Can you check in this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python), for **Identity-based connections** you need to give the **storage account URL** not the storage name. See in [this](https://i.imgur.com/LvBNUhi.png).

Comment: There is no trigger yet, i havent deployed the funciton code but the infrastructure only. I manually created an azure function and performed all the steps for managed identity but it still complains about azurewebjobssstorage if i provide an invalid or remove it

Comment: @rdhaundiyal I believe its just a warning message as function works as expected for me after having the banner too. Refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/diagnostic-events/azfd0002, it says you will get this message when you will have different value other than connection string in `AzureWebJobsStorage`

Answer (score 1):

> The function is working fine but I am getting a message in azure portal saying "Value of "AzureWebJobsStorage" app setting is invalid."

This looks like an **information** level log. If you will click on the banner, you see see some links and error code like below-

[image]

- Click on the Help link, you will be navigated to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/diagnostic-events/azfd0002) wherein it says below-

[image]

- In our case we have set the value as storage account name whereas **AzureWebJobsStorage** expects connection string. AFAIK, as we are passing a different value than connection string we are getting the message.
- There is also a suppress condition which says about key vault references.

[image]

- My function work as expected.

[image]

- I have raised a [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/120878) to include the managed identity related information in the error code page. You can refer to it for more details about the message.